# How to add a reset password button in django-administration

Tags: django, python-3.x

How to add a reset password  button in django-administration. And also Reset password button act like Email verification[I want like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLWsU.png)

Answer (score 1):

As per [**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-a-password-reset-feature):

> the presence of the **admin_password_reset** named URL will cause a **“forgotten your password?”** link to appear on the default admin log-in page under the password box.

So, if you want to add a reset password feature in admin site login page, you need to add the following views in `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns += [
    path(
        'admin/password_reset/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(),
        name='admin_password_reset',
    ),  # <-- This one will make the forgot password link appear in admin site.
    path(
        'admin/password_reset/done/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(),
        name='password_reset_done',
    ),
    path(
        'reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
        name='password_reset_confirm',
    ),
    path(
        'reset/done/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(),
        name='password_reset_complete',
    ),
]
```

Comment: But How i add this type of button (As per picture[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLWsU.png)) to django admin template.